# Use Javascript to get value from plaintext API

Tags: javascript, jquery

*I would prefer native Javascript but jQuery will be fine as a second option.*

I want to use a plain text API such as the one offered at this site:

[blockchain.info plain text bitcoin blockchain parsing API](https://blockchain.info/q)

Then I want to use Javascript/jQuery to get that value and use it elsewhere in my code.

I have found this example using jQuery (Native is prefered):

```
$.get("https://blockchain.info/q/addressbalance/1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa", function(response) { alert(response) });
```

However this alerts with the value, I want to get that value into a Javascript variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

`$.get("https://blockchain.info/address/1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa", function(response) { alert(response) });`

`response` is the variable that holds the output.

EDIT: it's important to know that the variable response is only accessible in the curly braces.

So let's say you wanted to call a function and pass the output to it.

`$.get("https://blockchain.info/address/1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa", function(response) { my_function(response) });`

```
function my_function( response ) {

   //the variable response holds the text you want.
   //EDIT: response, not my_function. Sorry about that.

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var value;
$.get("https://blockchain.info/address/1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa", function(response) { value=response; });
```

After the ajax call you will get the value in the variale `value`